# speed control of Permanent magnet synchronous machine using digital signal processor

Tags: pmsm

From a literature I found the entire speed control algorithm include SVPWM is implemented by a DSP TMS320F2808 with a clock frequency of 100 MHz.The speed loop and both d and q current loop sampling periods is 250 and 60 microsecond.
My question
Q.1 how the sampling time are different for both loop if they are sampled in same interrupt routine to calculate the necessary switching signal for field orient  control?
Q .2  How I set different sampling time for different loop in same program?
Q.3 Here actually what is the meaning of Sampling time?Is it related to Dynamics or stability in field orient control?
 I can't relate this to sampling of signal at required interval   I am confused little how field orient control actually work in PMSM using DSP.

Comment: Who says *they are sampled in same interrupt routine*? And, if they were, where's the problem?

Comment: So they are using outdated value of speed/theta for inner current control to generate Id and Iq . What I found previously that both current and speed are sampled at starting position of every triangular carrier signal which dictates switching frequency and also sampling time of control algorithm from Texas instruments site.

Comment: Which literature?

Comment: I didn't find it sry my fault.speed loop ,current loop are handled in different interrupt routine with different sample time and they are induce delay in computing which can be approximate as first order function.Does switching frequency of pwm anyway relate to the sampling of current loop?